# How to remove .com or Extension on Twitter Follower Count Button?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter

I have an issue with my script without url extension it works, but if I insert .com or any url extension the count will not work on my script. e.g: if I put google I get a reading of million follower but with url extension it will be zero. Please help how do I remove that extension`<a class="twitter-follow-button" href="https://twitter.com/google" data-show-screen-name="false">0 Follower</a>` - it works but with extension its zero.

In .php `<a class="twitter-follow-button" href="https://twitter.com/{$domain}" data-show-screen-name="false">0 Follower</a>`

Sorry if I'm having difficulties in explaining but I hope you guys can able to understand. Thank you

I having an issue as on my php it will be like this

Below is my script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" >

<script>

window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>

</br></br></br>
<a class="twitter-follow-button" href="https://twitter.com/google.com" data-show-screen-name="false">No Data </a>

</br></br></br></br></br>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "url extension"?

Comment: .com, .org, .net something like that

Comment: Surely `twitter.com/google` shows the number of followers for the `@google` twitter account, whereas `twitter.com/google.com` doesn't exist because it's not a valid twitter handle. So this is correct.

Comment: in my php im using ```$domain``` which the output will be ```google.com``` thats the problem i need to remove the '.com'

Comment: You can check in my https://codepen.io/dkpramis-dubai/pen/gOaWaXG youll see what i mean. Thanks

Comment: `$hashtag = preg_replace("/\..*/", "",$domain);`

Comment: @Bansay wont work :( check out here in https://codepen.io/dkpramis-dubai/pen/gOaWaXG . Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: https://codepen.io/Banzay/pen/RwWVgRG

Comment: @Bansay, Thank you so much for your help. 

♡ ♥❤